# MySQL - Recovery data

Tags: mysql

I need help.

my computer has problem and not turn on more.

I got access the HD data from another computer.

there is a way to access my database? any way to recover my information?

I can only access HD in another computer.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MySql being a service, cannot operate if you try and access it from another computer. But one thing you can do is copy the data folder from MySqlServer folder, and paste it on the MySqlServer folder in a computer which is running. The chances are bleak, but I had recovered the data in same fashion once.

Comment: I tried.
but could not yet.
it does not recognize the data.